# How to load node bypassing domain access?

Tags: nodes, users, domain-access

I'm using the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module. One of its features is the 'Domain access option', which lets you can specify witch node is publish where.

I wrote drush script and I'm trying to load bunch of nodes from different domains. If I run drush script with site alias @X then only nodes from X domain will loaded, otherwise `node_load()` return `FALSE`.

How can I load node bypassing domain access settings?